# Error com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token

Tags: java, json, file, jackson

Trying to read a JSON file and serialize it to java object, I wrote a method:

```
public static PostPojo readFile(String titleFile){
    String pathJSONFile = "src/main/resources/"+titleFile+".json";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
         objectMapper.readValue(pathJSONFile,PostPojo.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return postPojo;
}
```

but it produces an error:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'src': was expecting (JSON 
    String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
    at [Source: (String)"src/main/resources/ninetyNinthPost.json"; line: 1, column: 4]
    at utils.ApiUtils.readFile(ApiUtils.java:71)
    at ApiApplicationRequest.getValue(ApiApplicationRequest.java:31)
```

My JSON file from which values are calculated

```
[ {
 "userId" : 10,
 "id" : 99,
 "title" : "temporibus sit alias delectus eligendi possimus magni",
 "body" : "quo deleniti praesentium dicta non quod\naut est 
 molestias\nmolestias et officia quis nihil\nitaque dolorem quia"
} ]
```

My java object class

```
public class PostPojo {

private int userId;
private int id;
private String title;
private String body;
public PostPojo() {
}

public PostPojo(int userId, int id, String title, String body) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PostModel{" +
            "userId=" + userId +
            ", id=" + id +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", body='" + body + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

I really don't understand what is the reason.As I understand it, reading in the documentation, it should read the file and present it in the java class. Any sugestions?

Comment: Post your JSON and your `PostPojo` class.

Comment: share `"src/main/resources/ninetyNinthPost.json"` please

Comment: added what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method signature supposed to get a file path as first argument. You may pass a JSON String as first argument or you could use the method signature with a File Object as first argument, like this:

```
public static PostPojo[] readFile(String titleFile){
    String pathJSONFile = "src/main/resources/"+titleFile+".json";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File jsonFile = new File(pathJSONFile);

    PostPojo[] postPojo = null;
    try {
        postPojo = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, PostPojo[].class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return postPojo;
}
```

EDIT: Since your file defines a wrapping array around the object you have to parse it as array. Afterwards you may return it as an array like i did in my edited answer or you just return the first array record.

Comment: Cannot deserialize instance of `model.PostPojo` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: fixed it, the example file was missing before my initial post.

Comment: Can you tell me why then the object is postPojo is null , if we write data from a file to it?

Comment: In my example i declare the variable before the try catch block and initialize it to null. Then the file gets parsed and if everything´s ok the variable postPojo contains the data from the file. it works in my local setup with your example data.

Comment: and I have zero returns))